# Cleaning Up HTACCESS - Combine Rules?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am cleaning up some old code in my HTACCESS file to make it slimmer and cannot figure out how to combine these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/?$ /this/is-my-url.asp [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /this/is-my-url.asp?from=$1 [NC,L]
```

My goal is to combine both of these rules in to one.  I only need the "from=" if there is a referral code passed in.

Is it doable?

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't care if the `from` parameter is blank, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2(?:/([a-z0-9_-]+)|)/?$ /this/is-my-url.asp?from=$1 [NC,L]
```

The `/([a-z0-9_-]+)` part of the expression becomes optional, but the `from=` part of the query string will still be there, meaning you're going to get an empty value if the referral code isn't passed in.

Comment: This works!  Whether it is there and blank or not there, same thing.  Thanks - good idea!